# Gson:serialize object with list of another objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, android, gson

I have class GamePresenter with collection of Players:

```
public class GamePresenter extends MvpBasePresenter<IMainGameView> {

public ArrayList<BoxPlayer> BoxPlayersColl;

public GamePresenter()
{
    TestPlayerInit testPlayerInit=new  TestPlayerInit();
    BoxPlayersColl=testPlayerInit.BoxPlayersColl;


}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "GamePresenter [data1=" + BoxPlayersColl + "]";
}
```

}

`TestPlayerInit` simple create all Players, insert is into BoxPlayerCollection.

So, each BoxPlayer have some fields and Map of another objects:

```
public class BoxPlayer {

public Player PlayerObj;

public Integer Id;
public String Description;
// getters,setters...

public Map<Integer,PlayerData> IntToPlayerData;
```

}

`Player` class:

```
 public  int Id;
 public String NickName;
 // getters setters

public Player(int id,String nickName)
{
    Id=id;
    NickName=nickName;
}
```

And PlayerData is simple POJO:

```
public class PlayerData{
public BoxPlayer Player1;   
public BoxPlayer Player2;

public VotedBoxPlayer(BoxPlayer player1, BoxPlayer player2)
{
    Player1=player1;
    Player2=player2;
}
```

}

So, i want to serialize it and store in SharedPrederence.

I use `Gson` lib:

```
 public String serializeGamePresenter(GamePresenter gamePresenter)
{
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String gamePresenterJSON= gson.toJson(_gamePresenter);
    return gamePresenterJSON;
}
```

But, when i use this method- application freeze, memory allocation crash application.

Can you help me, how to serialize this object to JSON?

P.S. when i try to serialize `ArrayList` BoxPlayerColl- it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing all of your information, like what is TestPlayerInit?
Regardless, you have created an issue with the fact that you are:

The class `BoxPlayer` has references to `PlayerData` in the `public Map<Integer,PlayerData> IntToPlayerData;`

Player Data has variables of type `BoxPlayer`

In Summary, when the json serialization is occurring, you are getting into a cyclic reference loop, an endless loop, causing the JVM to crash.

You need to evaluate the structure of your objects. There should not be a case where class A references B that references A again.

Comment: p.s. it not works when class BoxPlayer does not contains Map<Integer,BoxPlayer>.  But ArrayList<BoxPlayer> serialize works.